# C++ string.compare()

Tags: c++, pointers, string

I'm building a comparator for an assignment, and I'm pulling my hair out because this seems to simple, but I can't figure it out.

This function is giving me trouble:

```
int compare(Word *a, Word *b)
{
    string *aTerm = a->getString();
    string *bTerm = b->getString();

    return aTerm->compare(bTerm);
}
```

Word::getString returns a string*

Error:

```
 In member function `virtual int CompWordByAlpha::compare(Word*, Word*)':   
  no matching function for call to...
```

...followed by a bunch of function definitions.

Any help?

Comment: I think you omitted the most important part of the error message.

Comment: Next time post the whole error message!

Comment: You bet.  I didn't think it was crucial as string is a part of the standard library of C++, and I knew it wasn't an issue with my classes and their functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing a string to a string pointer, and that's not valid.  You want

```
   return aTerm->compare(*bTerm);
```

Comment: That did it.  I don't understand why the asterisk was required, as bTerm is already a *string.  Does that mean the basic_string::compare method requires a **basic_string parameter?

Comment: string::compare() takes a string reference as a parameter, not a pointer.  Passing *bTerm dereferences the pointer so that you pass a string object, not a string pointer.

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense.  Thanks Fred!

Answer (score 3):

You aren't getting the different uses of the * operator. The use of the * in "string* bTerm = b->getString()" means "bTerm is a pointer to a string". The use of the * inside of compare(*bTerm) means "take the value of the location pointed to by bTerm" instead of just using compare(bTerm) which simply attempts to compare the value of bTerm itself, which is a hex address.

This is also happening on the left side of that call:

```
aTerm->compare(*bTerm); //this statement
(*aTerm).compare(*bTerm); //is the same as this statement
```

The -> operator just reduces the amount of typing required.

P.S.: This kind of stuff you could have easily figured out from Google or your programming textbook. Although others may disagree, I don't feel that questions about completely basic syntax have any place on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I learned Java first and I'm just starting C++, so I'm still getting used to having to consciously manage pointers and references.  I found Fred's answer extremely helpful for getting my program to compile, and I found yours extremely informative.

Now, how do I print output?

;)

Comment: You print output with std::cout.